# How to add several UIImages to one base UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I know there has to be a way to take one base image (in my case a transparent 4096x4096 base layer) and adding several dozen (up to 100) very small (100x100) images to it in different locations.  BUT I cannot figure out how to do it:  Assume for the following that `imageArray` has many elements, each containing a NSDictionary with the following structure:

```
@{
@"imagename":imagename,
@"x":xYDict[@"x"],
@"y":xYDict[@"y"]
}
```

Now, here is the code (that is not working. all I have is a transparent screen...and the performance is STILL horrible...about 1-2 seconds per "image" in the loop...and massive memory use.

```
NSString *PNGHeatMapPath = [[myGizmoClass dataDir] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HeatMap.png"];

        @autoreleasepool
        {
            CGSize theFinalImageSize = CGSizeMake(4096, 4096);
            NSLog(@"populateHeatMapJSON: creating blank image");
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theFinalImageSize, NO, 0.0);
            UIImage *theFinalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            for (NSDictionary *theDict in imageArray)
            {
                NSLog(@"populateHeatMapJSON: adding: %@",theDict[@"imagename"]);

                UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:theDict[@"imagename"]];

                [image drawInRect:CGRectMake([theDict[@"x"] doubleValue],[theDict[@"y"] doubleValue],image.size.width,image.size.height)];

            }
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theFinalImage);

            theFinalImage = nil;

            [imageData writeToFile:PNGHeatMapPath atomically:YES];

            NSLog(@"populateHeatMapJSON: PNGHeatMapPath = %@",PNGHeatMapPath);

        }
```

I KNOW I am misunderstanding `UIGraphics` contexts...can someone help me out? I am trying to superimpose a bunch of UIImages on the blank transparent canvas at certain x,y locations, get the final image and save it.

PS: This is also .. if the simulator is anything to go by ... leaking like heck.  It goes up to 2 or 3 gig...
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I did find this and tried it but it requires me to rewrite the entire image, copy that image to a new one and add to that new one.  Was hoping for a "base image", "add this image", "add that image", "add the other image" and get the new base image without all the copying:

Is this as good as it gets?

```
+(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage
          inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
          atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
[bgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, bgImage.size.width, bgImage.size.height)];
[fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( point.x, point.y, fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
 }
```

Comment: You are getting the image `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` before you have actually drawn anything. Move this call to after your loop and before the `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`

Comment: One thing I noticed...the @3x bit me. I wanted a final 4096 canvas no matter the scale of screen. BUT the reason this is such a memory monster as-is is that it made the image 12288x12288 (I am testing on iphone 6 plus simulator) ... :(  Oh, well. My bad.  Paul: I will try your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: Paul, if you put this in terms of "responding" to the question, I will accept it.  Worked!  Thanks!  (and MUCH faster AND memory efficient than the `drawImage` attempt I tried)~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the image `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` before you have actually drawn anything. Move this call to after your loop and before the `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`

Your drawing actually occurs on the line

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake([theDict[@"x"] doubleValue],[theDict[@"y"] doubleValue],image.size.width,image.size.height)];
```

the function `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` gives you the image of the current contents of the context so you need to ensure that you have done all your drawing before you grab the image.